# How to convert slot_types of messages to actual data types

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am currently implementing a little python script that takes parameters for actions from a string and automatically populates an action goal to send it to the action server. The goal obviously defines all the correct message types like `string`, `float64`, etc. The problem is, that I read these params from a string that does not necessarily tell me the type, e.g. "30" could be 30, 30.0, or '30', that would depend on the type specified in the goal. I know that for ROS message types like `std_msgs/Float64` one can use `roslib.message.get_message_class("std_msgs/Float64")` to get the correct python class. But for entries like `float64` this becomes more complicated. Even using `std_msgs/Float64` does not help because that also contains a `float64` in the `data` field. My question is, is there a function to get the python type `numpy.float64` from `'float64'` in the message definition?

I know there is [check_type](https://github.com/ros/genpy/blob/indigo-devel/src/genpy/message.py#L187-L267) but that only checks the type to raise an exception but does not return it.

I am on Indigo btw. Here a very small example

```
def create_goal(str_array):
    g = myactionGoal()
    for s, slot, t in zip(str_array, g.__slots__, g._slot_types):
        t = magic_function_to_get_type_from_string(t)
        setattr(g, slot, t(s))
    return g
```

EDIT:

One way of achieving this for simple datatypes would be:

```
def create_goal(str_array):
    g = myactionGoal()
    for s, slot, t in zip(str_array, g.__slots__, g._slot_types):
        t = type(getattr(g, slot)) # Get type of default value
        setattr(g, slot, t(s))
    return g
```

Because after the creation of the goal message, all the slots are intialised with the correct data type. This however does not work for things like `float64[]` because that would only tell me that it is supposed to be a list but not the expected type of the elements.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240035/how-to-convert-slot_types-of-messages-to-actual-data-types/) by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a possible solution: `pydoc.locate` is able to import datatypes based on string descriptors. Most of the basic datatypes in the messages are actually `numpy` types. Hence, `t = locate("numpy."+t)` solves most of the problems. `string` has to be shortened to `str` and `char` doesn't exist and has to be replaced by `str` as well but the rest matches quite well. By just removing `[]` like `t = t.replace("[]","")` in case of arrays you can find the type they are supposed to contain.

Still grateful for any other comments or possible solutions though. Just thought I'd share my findings ;)

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0